# How can I upload text and file in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload both text data and a file to django server using angular for the front-end,
here is my models in django

```
#models.py
class UploadChapter(models.Model):
    chapter_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=chapters)
    chapter_file = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
    student = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(Supervisor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=status, default="Pending")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.student} - {self.chapter_number}'
```

for the serializer I wrote this code

```
#serializers.py
class UploadChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadChapter
        fields = ['chapter_number', 'chapter_file', 'student', 'supervisor', 'status']
```

and for the views i wrote this code

```
#views.py
@csrf_exempt
def ChapterApi(request, id=0):
    if request.method=='GET':
        chapters=UploadChapter.objects.all()
        chaptersSerializer=UploadChapterSerializer(chapters, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(chaptersSerializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        chaptersData=JSONParser().parse(request)
        chaptersSerializer=UploadChapterSerializer(data=chaptersData)
        if chaptersSerializer.is_valid():
            chaptersSerializer.save()
            return JsonResponse('Added Successfully', safe=False)
        return JsonResponse('Failed', safe=False)
```

so am getting errors from the JSONParser and I really dont know how to do this, I need help please

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for myself, i wrote a class-based view instead of the function based, here is the code for it

```
class ChapterView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        chapter_serializer = UploadChapterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if chapter_serializer.is_valid():
            chapter_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse('Chapter Sent Successfully', safe=False)
        else:
            return JsonResponse('upload fail', safe=False)
    def get(self, request):
        chapter = UploadChapter.objects.all()
        chapterSerializer = UploadChapterSerializer(chapter, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(chapterSerializer.data, safe=False)
```